# Twilio device release

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio client in JavaScript. How do I make my presence offline so other users will not call me?

To connect I use `Twilio.Device.setup()`. Is there a `Device.goOffline()` or some other method like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here,

There is indeed an `offline()` function. [See the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device#offline).

Comment: The documentation says offline is an event handler that will fire when the device goes offline. My question is how to explicitly or manually make my device go offline ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the docs for [destroy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#destroy)?

> *Destroys the device. Terminates active and pending connections. This will trigger the offline event handler. Device will not be able to make or receive new connections until you call `Twilio.Device.setup()` again.*